# Getting the card info for the expansion slots of a pc

Tags: batch-file

So what I am trying to do is get the name , model, type  what ever I can from the cards in the motherboard slots.  I need to do this via a batch file.

How do I go about getting this info?  I looked in `systeminfo` and did not see them there and don't believe that are in the WMIC.  Is there another command that may have that info?

IF if use

```
 wmic SYSTEMSLOT get connectorpinout, connectortype, description, manufacturer, model, name, number, partnumber, slotDesignation, tag
```

it will output like so,  which may work.. the pc I am using has no slots used..

```
                  {0}            System Slot                       System Slot                      PCIE x16         System Slot 0
                  {0}            System Slot                       System Slot                      PCIE x1          System Slot 1
                  {0}            System Slot                       System Slot                      M.2 2280         System Slot 2
```

Thanks again

Comment: Which cards? One answer will not provide them all, so technically your question is too broad. BTW, it is clear from your previous questions that you're trying to create a batch script to output hardware information for a PC. I would advise you that this would be much simpler if you use a different scripting language, WSH and PowerShell should be available to you and would serve the purpose better.

Comment: Any cards in an expansion  slot.  This is the last part of the batch file I need.  Problem is not all PCs are windows 10 some are 7 and some are xp.  The PCs are very hard to get to thus why I am trying to do it all from a program instead of opening them.  I did see SYSTEMSLOTS in WMIC  it seems to do as needed but maybe not.  Need to do more testings for that.

Comment: As I've stated, your question is too broad, this site helps with a single specific issue, not with providing you with the commands for every piece of hardware in your PC's. To start you off, how does the output from this single line [tag:batch-file] help you? `@"%__AppDir__%wbem\wmic.exe" Path Win32_PnPEntity Where "PNPDeviceID like '%%VEN%%'" Get Caption,PNPDeviceID,Manufacturer`. _BTW, WSH is available in Windows even earlier than XP, so that is not an excuse._

Comment: @Compo what you posted worked, it shows the name and type of the cards in the slots. It just also shows a lot of other things.  what I was trying did not work. Is there any way to filter out the stuff not in the card slots?

Comment: As I stated, your question is too broad, all cards is not specific enough. You will probably want, instead of using a single command and trying to filter everything, many different commands. For example, `Win32_VideoController`, `Win32_SoundDevice` etc. I would suggest you take a look at some WMI reference documentation, to see which you need.

Comment: @Compo I did notice a pattern..  if you made the PNPDeviceID only find "PCI\VEN_"  and that is not "PCI\VEN_808" and Manufacturer not contain the word "Standard"  Then it would return just the devices in the slots..  Not sure if the deviceID changes on different PCs or if all onboard devices start with PCI\VEN_808...   I have to say this is exciting for me to see it work lol.

Comment: As I stated you can try to modify the `Where` filters, e.g. `@"%__AppDir__%wbem\wmic.exe" Path Win32_PnPEntity Where "PNPDeviceID Like '%%VEN_%%' And Not Manufacturer Like '%%Standard%%'" Get Caption,PNPDeviceID,Manufacturer`. But it is unlikely that this will always work for the purposes you need on any PC.

Comment: @Compo thanks! this solution seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@"%__AppDir__%wbem\wmic.exe" Path Win32_PnPEntity Where "PNPDeviceID Like '%%PCI\\VEN_%%' And Not Manufacturer Like '%%Standard%%' And Not PNPDeviceID Like '%%PCI\\VEN_808%%'" Get Caption,PNPDeviceID,Manufacturer.
```

This seem to work for me, Thanks to Compo for the help.  What I found is all the devices that were not in slots seem to have the PCI\VEN_808 prefix.  except for a few that gave the manufacture type of standard.   This may not work 100% but it product 1 or 2 false readings which by reading the description you should  know it was not a card in a slot.

I will leave this up for now until a better solution comes along.

Comment: From [tag:cmd] the wildcard for zero or more characters is `%` and from a [tag:batch-file] it's `%%`. As the string begins with `PCI\ `, you do not need to precede those two with wildcards. Please also note that the underscore, `_` is  a wildcard for one character. You should therefore escape your literal underscore by placing it inside `[]` _(square brackets)_. `@"%__AppDir__%wbem\wmic.exe" Path Win32_PnPEntity Where "PNPDeviceID Like 'PCI\\VEN[_]%%' And Not Manufacturer Like '%%Standard%%' And Not PNPDeviceID Like 'PCI\\VEN[_]808%%'" Get Caption,PNPDeviceID,Manufacturer`.